# How to send just arbitrary scalar value with Metrics?

Tags: java, metrics, dropwizard

I can't find an ability to send just some scalar values with [Metrics](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.2.0/)!

`Meter`s allow just marking of time instants.

`Gauge` generates a value by calling stored function.

`Counter` cn only increase or decrease.

Can I have entity, that allows me just send some values I want?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a Gauge, for example

```
registry.register(name(SessionStore.class, "the-answer"), new Gauge<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return 42;
    }
});
```

See https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.2.0/manual/core.html#

Comment: Don't you send 42 all the time? I want to send different values at different moments. Or registering is the same as sending? What is the purpuse of functional lofgic here?

Comment: you can replace 42 with a call to your value-providing dependency, e.g. a service of some sorts that reports the values you need. Maybe you should tell us what values you want to publish?